# Extract integers from 2D Arraylist whose sum is between a range

Tags: c#

I'm writing code for a .NETMF application and need to create a function which accepts 2 params `int min, int max` and returns an array of integers `returnedArr` from a generated 2D Arraylist `arr` were the sum of integers inside `returnedArr` will be between `min` and `max` and also I will not know what the size or contents of `arr` will be prior to calling the method. Only 1 integer per Arraylist inside `arr` will be selected.

```
        public ArrayList GetNums(int min, int max)
        {
            //arr will be structured like this
            //var arr = new ArrayList
            //{
            //    new ArrayList {10, 34, 56, 60},
            //    new ArrayList {3, 23, 56, 78, 65, 42},
            //    new ArrayList {53, 56, 76}
            //};

            var returnedArr = new ArrayList();

            var arr = GenerateArraylistValues();

            //solution code here...

            return returnedArr;
        }

        var returnedArr = new ArrayList();

        var arr = GenerateArraylistValues();

        //solution code here...

        return returnedArr;
    }
```

A sample would be `GetNums(130,140);`
Return arraylist could be `Arraylist{56,23,53}`

Also bear in mind that I'm confined to using Arraylists so I can't use generic lists, I was thinking that some sort of `foreach loop` would do the job but can't get my head around how this would work since I no idea what the size of `arr` will be before hand

-----------SAMPLE 'arr' VALUES---------

```
var arr = new ArrayList
{
    new ArrayList { 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,55,56,59,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,90,93,96,99,102},
    new ArrayList { 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,55,56,59,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,90,93,96,99,102},
    new ArrayList { 39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,53,54,55,59,60,61,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,91,92,94,95,97,98,100,101,115,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,129,132,135,138,141},
    new ArrayList { 60,100,140,180},
    new ArrayList { 41,43,45,55,81,83,85,95,121,123,125,135},
    new ArrayList { 39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,53,54,55,59,60,61,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,91,92,94,95,97,98,100,101,115,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,129,132,135,138,141},
    new ArrayList { 3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,57,63}
};
```

Comment: Why not `Arraylist{65,65}` or `Arraylist{65,66}`? By the specs you give here I'd say `var x = (min+max)/2; return new ArrayList{x, x}` would be enough. But is it?

Comment: Hello, it has to pick 1 integer from each arraylist, so in the above sample it would be 3 numbers, but in others it could be more or less

Comment: Any other requirements to the program? How about starting with the smallest number from each, then replacing with the next larger number until you get over `min`? You would have to do the up-front sorting, but then just do substitutions and the math against a vector. What about the case that even the smallest are over `max` or the largest under `min`?

Comment: How about in the case of multiple matching sets? Is it ok for the program to return the same single set every time?

Answer (score 0):

If the 'arr' is not huge, using recursion and brute force:

```
    public ArrayList GetNums(int min, int max, ArrayList arr)
    {
        var results = new ArrayList();

        //nothing in the arr?
        if (arr.Count == 0)
            return results;

        //arr has only one list inside
        if(arr.Count == 1)
        {
            foreach(int a in (ArrayList)arr[0])
            {
                if(a >= min && a <= max)
                {
                    var r = new ArrayList();
                    r.Add(a);
                    results.Add(r);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        //arr has two or more lists inside
        ArrayList firstList = (ArrayList)arr[0];
        ArrayList remainingArr = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            remainingArr.Add(arr[i]);
        }

        foreach (int a in firstList)
        {
            var tempResults = GetNums(min - a, max - a, remainingArr);
            foreach(ArrayList result in tempResults)
            {
                var newResult = new ArrayList();
                newResult.Add(a);
                newResult.AddRange(result);
                results.Add(newResult);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

The result is a list of solutions. First valid solution for your example arr is {10, 65, 56}

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code with 'arr' containing 6 arraylists with 50 integers approx each ranging from 20-140, I tested from min-max of 600-700 but the results count was zero

Comment: If possible, please post a sample 'arr' and min max so that I can debug the code easier. Thanks

Comment: The algorithm, although slow, seems produces correct answer. However, for your dataset, it run out of memory on my computer. Solutions are too many. 
Ways to improve the performance:
1. sort the list(it seems already so)
2. using binary search for single list

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look at the binary search option

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to have the same result, of the minimum values, each and every time, then what you could do is to:

1. start with the smallest value of each sub-array,
2. sort the remaining values, tracking their source sub-array,
3. and move up the sorted values until you've met or exceeded the specified `min`

An example of such functionality (using LINQ for brevity, and converting back to `ArrayList`) would be as such:

```
public static ArrayList GetNums(int min, int max)
{
    var arr = GenerateArraylistValues();

    // Initialize our results with the minimum values from each array.
    var results = arr.Cast<ArrayList>().Select(sub => sub.Cast<int>().Min()).ToList();
    var others = new List<UnionItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
    {
        others = new List<UnionItem>(others
                    // Concatenate the arrays together.
                    .Union(((ArrayList)arr[i]).Cast<int>()
                    // Don't need the min value, which we will start at already. (Optional)
                    .Where(val => val != results[i])
                    // Create the UnionItem, to hold the value and the original array source.
                    .Select(val => new UnionItem(val, i))));
    }

    // Order our combined values.
    others = new List<UnionItem>(others.OrderBy(val => val.Value));
    using (var next = others.GetEnumerator())
    {
        // Progress through the combined values until we (a) meet or exceed min, or (b) run out of values.
        while ((results.Sum() < min) && (next.MoveNext()))
        {
            // Update the list of result values according to the UnionItem source.
            results[next.Current.Source] = next.Current.Value;
        }
    }

    // Once through our calculation, check now if we've successfully met the conditions.
    int sum = results.Sum();
    if (sum >= min && sum <= max)
    {
        return new ArrayList(results);
    }
    else
    {
        // Whatever happens if no valid match.
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}

private class UnionItem
{
    public readonly int Value;   // Holds the value from the array.
    public readonly int Source;  // Holds the index of the source array.
    public UnionItem(int value, int source)
    {
        Value = value;
        Source = source;
    }
}
```

I've created the `UnionItem` class, simply so we can do the tracking of the source array for each value, to substitute back correctly our results.